# String with numbers output formating

Tags: output-formatting

Is there something similar to `print("blah blah is %d", 5)` in python? In order to print `"blah blah is 5"`?

Comment: `Print["blah blah is ", 5]`?

Comment: Wait, why is this off topic?

Comment: In python doing comma splicing is seen as bad practice, so wanted to avoid `Print["blah blah is ", 5]` That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm):

```
StringForm["blah blah is `1` and other blah is `2`", 5, 10]
```

> blah blah is 5 and other blah is 10

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html):

```
StringTemplate["blah blah blah is `first`"][<|"first"->1|>]
```

> ```
> blah blah blah is 1
> ```

which has the advantage that you can assign your template and easily call it frequently (here, I'm using a simpler form than above):

```
template = StringTemplate["blah blah blah is ``"]

Map[template, {1,2,3,4}]
```

> ```
> {"blah blah blah is 1", "blah blah blah is 2", "blah blah blah is 3", "blah blah blah is 4"}
> ```

You might then use [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) or [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) or similar functions to actually "print" your statements, but this isn't a common paradigm in Wolfram Language.

Comment: I don't like StringTemplate because of things like: ``StringTemplate["blah blah blah is `first`"][<|"first"->1/2|>]``.

Comment: @CarlWoll What behaviour would you prefer? I feel as though in python, `print('x, y, %d', 1/2)` would also print `'x, y, 0.5'`... But in any case, I only wanted to add it as an option here. `StringForm` is probably closer to what the user wanted :)